# Laravel login not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I tried to create a basic login, but somehow it did not work correctly.

My Form looks like this:

```
   <form role="form" method="POST" action="/auth/login" class="form col-md-12 center-block">
      {!! csrf_field() !!}

       <div class="form-group">
           <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Email">
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" name="password" placeholder="Passwort">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
         </div>
     </form>
```

My Login routes look like this:

```
# Login, Logout
Route::get('auth/login', ['as' => 'newSession', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin']);
Route::post('auth/login', ['as' => 'createSession', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin']);
Route::get('auth/logout', ['as' => 'destroySession', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout']);
```

My login form looks ok at this url :

> http://localhost/myApp/public/

When I press login I get an error:

> Object not found 404

Url looks like this then

> http://localhost/auth/login

I want to redirect the user to product/home (folder product inside the product folder home.blade.php), after the user is logged in.

how do I solve this?

Comment: If I remember right, L 5.2.* has `@getLogin`, but it should be `@login`. Try renaming.

Comment: ok, but did you try it?

Comment: tried it I dont know excatly if it work, it loads quicly and I am at the same page with the same url

Comment: how did you served your project ? in your Web service root or artisan serve  ?

Comment: @MasoudHaghbin webservice root

Comment: use artisan serve and see if problem continues or not

Answer (score 0):

You are POSTing to the wrong URL, try this:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="/myApp/public/auth/login" class="form col-md-12 center-block">
                {!! csrf_field() !!}

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Email">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" name="password" placeholder="Passwort">
                </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
                    </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: sry did not work my url looks like this now `http://localhost/myApp/public/myApp/auth/login`

Comment: Yes that's normal, because you have wrong configuration for the document root in your web server configuration. You should point the web server to the public directory.

Comment: what is your webserver?

Comment: xampp, would like to to go into a chat?

Comment: You need to add the server configuration to your question, in order to point the change. The file should be located at: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache<version>\conf\httpd.conf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121455/discussion-between-mina-abadir-and-alex-oxilg).

Answer (score 0):

You can define your url like following with the route name. Then you don't need to think about the url.

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('createSession') }}" class="form col-md-12 center-block">
```

Comment: it keeps redirecting me to the login strange

Comment: Are you hitting to that postLogin method or directly going to login page?

Comment: hmm do not understand

Comment: When you are submitting form, does it go to postLogin function?